# Responsive (Mobile First) Website not working properly, even though Viewport and Media Queries have been used

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, viewport

I'm developing a personal portfolio website for myself. I've planned to build the website as a responsive one. Starting from smartphone (720px x 1280px) until a Desktop resolution. But, I've just finished the Mobile Smartphone size only. Even though I've done the viewport and media queries, when I tested it on my smartphone which has 720px x 1280px resolution, the output is bad. This is also happening when I resize the PC Browser windows to 720px x 1280px. But, oddly, while I was working, I always checked the update in the Inspect Element features in PC Desktop with frame size: 720px x 1280px and it works really well. So, I'm rather confuse here, where's the problem exactly?

Here's my source code:

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Your source code is not visible

Comment: Why not using Bootstrap framework for responsive website.